# Почему не успевают генерироваться случайные числа?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Столкнулся с такой неприятной ситуацией. Нужно получить два случайных числа из одного метода. Сначала, в переменную X помещаем возвращаемое значение метода Remove, затем в Y снова помещаем результат работы того же метода.
Мне выводит одни и те же числа, например: (80; 80),  (-3; -3) и тп. Хотя через построчный Debug выводит разные X и Y. Такое чувство, что VisualStudio слишком быстро работает и Random не успевает сгенерировать новое число.

Вот код:

```
int x1, y1;
x1 = circle1.Remove();
y1 = circle1.Remove();
Console.WriteLine("(" + x1 + "; " + y1 + ")");
```

Ведомый метод:

```
public int Remove()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return rnd.Next(-99, 99);
}
```

Comment: Потому что вы слишком часто создаете новый ГСЧ.

Comment: Ага! То есть не успевает! А я то думал, что я туплю где-то.

Comment: Создайте рандом один раз, тогда проблем быть не должно.

Comment: @JürgenvonMarkoff нет. Прочтите еще раз.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx -- MSDN как обычно имеет ответы на простые вопросы, я на будущее - стоит читать справку.

Comment: @koks_rs все-таки вопросы разные - в том случае был явно указан seed, и это была единственная ошибка. Тут seed не указан.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложенный мой вариант с задержкой лучше рассматривать в самом крайнем случае, а еще лучше не рассматривать.
Лучше сделать как советует Vladislav Khapin

```
class Circle {
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    public int Remove()
    {
        return rnd.Next(-99, 99);
    }

}
```

Comment: Вот с этого и надо было начинать! А то вокруг, да около ...

Answer (score 5):

Конструктор без параметров у класса Random() использует внутри себя [Environment.TickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx) как seed и, поскольку вы инициализируете объект Random 2 раза за короткий промежуток времени, высока вероятность того, что seed у двух объектов класса Random будет одинаковый. Это и приводит к одинаковым числам.

Соответственно - или использовать один объект класса Random или обеспечивать каждый раз уникальность seed.

Как вариант реализации первого варианта - вынести объект Random как приватное статическое поле\свойство в классе, который у вас реализует метод Remove(), правда, стоит учитывать, что метод Next() не потокобезопасен.

Comment: Делать то что? =)

Comment: задержку ставте на пару милисекунд